# Catboost does not show plot when specifying plot=true in model.fit

Tags: catboost

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3WYl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3udw.png

Catboost doesnt show plot. I am using mac m1 arm. Jupyter is locally installed.

Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.3.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.3.0
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.6.2
nbconvert        : 6.5.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.11
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.1.1

Tried in safari and chrome. Tried everything i could. No idea what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coudnt solve it.

Installed anaconda and created env there. That did work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).